# Bootstrap - the column is pushed down incorrectly when title have 3 line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list article in my blog. Show three columns.

The problem is: when the title of the article has 3 line. The columns are pushed down if have 4 article.

Like this:

```
article 1            article 2           article 3

                     article 4
```

It should be like:

```
article 1            article 2           article 3

article 4
```

My code like:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 pb-90">
            <div class="post-prev-title">
                <h3>New trends in web design</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-30">
                Maecenas volutpat, diam enim sagittis uam, id porta ulamis. Sed id dolor consectetur fermentum nibh vomat
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 pb-90">
            <div class="post-prev-title">
                <h3>10 The article have 2 line, it will break four item in this </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-30">
                Maecenas volutpat, diam enim sagittis uam, id porta ulamis. Sed id dolor consectetur fermentum nibh vomat
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 pb-90">
            <div class="post-prev-title">
                <h3>New trends in web design</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-30">
                Maecenas volutpat, diam enim sagittis uam, id porta ulamis. Sed id dolor consectetur fermentum nibh vomat
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 pb-90">
            <div class="post-prev-title">
                <h3>New trends in web design</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-30">
                Maecenas volutpat, diam enim sagittis uam, id porta ulamis. Sed id dolor consectetur fermentum nibh vomat
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note**: click run code -> full page to show.

Or see my pen: https://codepen.io/vanloc/pen/RZqVXR

Have any method to resolve this problem?

The title is defined by the user, I can't control that.

Comment: ` col-md-3 col-lg-3` instead of ` col-md-4 col-lg-4`?

Comment: @Rajez Bootstrap auto divide 12 columns. I want to show 3 article in one rows. Have 12/4 = 3 rows. So, I using `col-md-4` instead of `col-md-3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Try Something Like This. Using this [Multiline Ellipses](https://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/qlFdp)

CSS

```
.post-prev-title h3
{
    display: block;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 1;/*restricting to 1 line*/
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: In responsive for 770px to 990px. It will show incorrect. You can see at i.imgur.com/z3HUHi1.png

Comment: @vanloc remove the clearfix div in between and give a try

Comment: I don't use any element have `clearfix` div. I test base on your answers.

Comment: but i found a clearfix div check from bottom, there is a clearfix div

Comment: Are you see on my pen? I test answer on @Henry answer. I forget to delete this in Codepen. You can see my screen shot. http://i.imgur.com/VcAoT4J.png in my real project. Seem the height of excerpt also affects to it. Using your CSS for an excerpt?

Comment: Ok. I apply the same CSS to excerpt. It's working perfectly. Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153167/discussion-between-vanloc-and-chandra-shekhar).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a clearfix div to set the row correctly if the heights are uneven!

An example of that is documented here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-responsive-resets

Or if you can use a LESS/SCSS mixin, that's demonstrated here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#less-mixins-clearfix

Here is that code snippet with the clearfix in. Please let me know if this isn't the solution you were looking for. Thanks!

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 pb-90">
            <div class="post-prev-title">
                <h3>New trends in web design</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-30">
                Maecenas volutpat, diam enim sagittis uam, id porta ulamis. Sed id dolor consectetur fermentum nibh vomat
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 pb-90">
            <div class="post-prev-title">
                <h3>10 The article have 2 line, it will break four item in this </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-30">
                Maecenas volutpat, diam enim sagittis uam, id porta ulamis. Sed id dolor consectetur fermentum nibh vomat
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 pb-90">
            <div class="post-prev-title">
                <h3>New trends in web design</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-30">
                Maecenas volutpat, diam enim sagittis uam, id porta ulamis. Sed id dolor consectetur fermentum nibh vomat
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- CLEARFIX DIV -->
        <div class="clearfix visible-lg visible-md-block"></div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 pb-90">
            <div class="post-prev-title">
                <h3>New trends in web design</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-30">
                Maecenas volutpat, diam enim sagittis uam, id porta ulamis. Sed id dolor consectetur fermentum nibh vomat
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in responsive for 770px to 990px. It will show incorrect. You can see at: http://i.imgur.com/z3HUHi1.png

Comment: I'm editing my response to include some helper classes to hide the clearfix on smaller breakpoints! @vanloc